# Get key based on a sub-attribute match

Tags: javascript, firebase

So if I have a tree structured as following in firebase then how can I fetch the unique key where the Name == "Employee 1" and this should return the key "LJrWJlgUPWUaPQx0ok09CswIkXg2" ?

```
"Users" : {
    "LJrWJlgUPWUaPQx0ok09CswIkXg2" : {
      "Shifts" : {
        "dfaskjhfkashdf" : {
          "endTime" : 1490907600,
          "startTime" : 1490878800
        }
      },
      "email" : "Employee1@gmail.com",
      "employeeId" : "LJrWJlgUPWUaPQx0ok09CswIkXg2",
      "fcmToken" : "eOVPmlxy9fc:APA91bEChCT-JwnH14yLrkWBdWBR-KJwj_FznOgwSzu-2JbL2hD5tRTl-7GkavLSihSzJMJ2_f7FjDhUgnU464EKNGaTUjoV0ZuLbJMlxtJeghhRCBDTbkm_J_yiH29IDXHVjmxbfVHw",
      "name" : "Employee 1",
      "password" : "Employee1",
      "startDate" : "2017-01-23"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this ought to do the trick:

```
firebase.database().ref('Users')
  .orderByChild('name')
  .equalTo('Employee 1')
  .limitToFirst(1)
  .once('value', snap => {
    let key = Object.keys(snap.val())[0]; // LJrWJlgUPWUaPQx0ok09CswIkXg2
    let user = snap.child(key).val(); // the whole user object
  });
```

Comment: This is a query that will find the *first* user with the specified name. If you have multiple users with the same name, it will only return one of them, so it's up to you to make sure that doesn't happen.

Comment: An upvote and a checkmark will help others know it worked, too :)